# Why adding COM component throws ReflectionTypeLoadException?

Tags: c#, winforms-interop

So, i am adding PDF COM component in one my project but it throws ReflectionTypeLoadException while the same component successfully adds  in another project.

i am using VS2015 & i get below error.

[image]

Comment: maybe the PDF COM component relies on some external dependency which you are missing in your project.
Compare the _References_ nodes from the two projects (the one which works and the one which does not) and check if the first contains some additional dependency which is missing in the second.

Comment: From the error, it looks like the tooling itself has failed; the error is in relation to an `AxToolboxItem` class, a method `CreateComponentsCore` which seems to be trying to load an `AxHost` type which is the **real** source of the type-load error.

Comment: There are a *lot* of PDF viewer libraries out there.  Opportunity knocks here, this old activex dog is well past its prime and it is time to retire it.  If you want to use it anyway then be sure to run the vendor's installer to get it onto your machine and sniff out any remaining problems by using the aximp.exe utility from the VS developer prompt.